# ¿Como programar respaldos automáticos diarios en Sql Server 2012 Express?

Tags: base-de-datos, sql-server-2012, .bat

Estoy utilizando el gestor de base de datos SQL Server 2012 Express y necesito hacer un respaldo de varias bases de datos a una hora determinada todos los días. Había probado realizando lo siguiente:

**Haciendo un .bat:**

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -S "SVRCOMPAQ\COMPAC12" -i "C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\prueba respaldo\ScriptRespaldo.sql" >> log.txt
```

**Y mi Script Sql:**

```sql
use cNombre_BD;

GO

DECLARE @archivo nvarchar(255) DECLARE @fecha varchar(MAX)

set @fecha = CONVERT(Varchar(max), GETDATE(),112) set @archivo = 'C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\prueba respaldo\Nombre_BD'+@fecha+'.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE cNombre_BD TO DISK = @archivo WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,
NAME = 'BackupNombre_BD', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10

declare @backupSetId as int select @backupSetId = position from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'cNombre_BD' and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=N'cNombre_BD' ) if @backupSetId is null begin raiserror(N'Error de comprobación. No se encuentra la información de copia de seguridad para la base de datos ''cNombre_BD''.', 16, 1) end RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = @archivo WITH FILE = @backupSetId, NOUNLOAD, NOREWIND

GO
```

Y el archivo `.bat` lo ejecuto con ayuda de una tarea programada en windows pero, al ejecutar la tarea, deja esto en el log:

> ```
> Se cambi¢ el contexto de la base de datos a 'Nombre_BaseDatos'. 
> No se puede abrir el dispositivo de copia de seguridad 'C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\prueba respaldo\Nombre_BaseDatos.bak'. 
> Error de sistema operativo 5(Acceso denegado.)
> Fin anomalo de BACKUP DATABASE. 
> Fin an¢malo de VERIFY DATABASE. –
> ```

Comment: "no me ha funcionado" no es la mejor descripción técnica de un problema. ¿Qué has verificado? ¿Hay mensajes de error? ¿Cuáles?

Comment: El archivo log me arroja los siguientes errores: Se cambi¢ el contexto de la base de datos a 'Nombre_BaseDatos'. / No se puede abrir el dispositivo de copia de seguridad 'C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\prueba respaldo\Nombre_BaseDatos.bak'. Error de sistema operativo 5(Acceso denegado.)/Fin anomalo de BACKUP DATABASE.
Fin an¢malo de VERIFY DATABASE.

Comment: El mensaje de error es bastante claro. El backup se ejecuta bajo el usuario de la base de datos. Sugiero que cambies la ruta. Las carpetas que están dentro de `\users` suelen ser privadas de cada usuario (real). SQL server crea una carpeta por defecto para backups durante la instalación, a la que si tiene permisos el usuario, a pesar de estar dentro de `\program files`, o puedes utilizar otra. Yo generalmente creo una carpeta `\bak` en la raíz de una unidad.

Comment: Ese era el problema el permiso de las carpetas, muchas gracias.

Comment: Escribí una respuesta para que la información no quede perdida en comentarios. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El mensaje de error del LOG es bastante claro.

Debes tener en cuenta que al lanzar una instrucción `backup database` dentro de un cliente de SQL, tal como `sqlcmd.exe`, el backup se ejecuta

- En el servidor de base de datos (por lo que las rutas como `c:\x\y\z` son de dicha máquina.
- Todo corre bajo el usuario que corre el servicio de la base de datos. En una instalación típica de SQL Server, con los valores por default, este usuario es creado por el instalador y tiene los permisos mínimos necesarios para ejecutar exitosamente el proceso de base de datos.

Dado que las carpetas que están dentro de `\users` suelen ser privadas de cada usuario real –que inicia sesión interactiva– del equipo, tienes dos alternativas:

- Colocar como destino una carpeta accesible al usuario de la base de datos o
- Darle permisos a tu carpeta privada de usuario al usuario de la base de datos, cosa no recomendable.

Mi sugerencia es **cambiar la ruta del archivo destino del backup**.

SQL server crea una carpeta por defecto para backups durante la instalación, a la que si tiene permisos el usuario, a pesar de estar dentro de `\program files` (se puede cambiar durante la instalación),

Puedes utilizar otra carpeta, fuera de las *normales* de Windows. Yo generalmente creo una carpeta `\bak` en la raíz de una unidad. También puedes valerte de la carpeta `\users\public`, aunque diría que quieres mantener un estricto control de quién tiene acceso a los archivos de backup de la base de datos.